# Best Practice to chain two functions,, AngularJs/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I have TWO functions.

One hides a modal when the 'close' button is clicked
The other function swipes right and changes the modal to another state/view.

I am having an issue with the modal NOT 'hiding' when the user swipes to the new state. I can see that it works but the modal remains on display and I was thinking that the best way to approach this is by chaining my two functions? Is this the correct terminology?

The TWO functions..

**HIDES the modal**

```
$scope.closetripInfo = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
```

**SWIPES right to reveal new .state**

```
$scope.onSwipeRight = function() {
  $state.go('app.current-trip');
}
```

**This worked! BUT..**
What I was thinking of doing is plugging in my exciting `closetripInfo` function into the `onSwipeRight` Like so:

```
$scope.onSwipeRight = function() {

  $scope.closetripInfo();  
  $state.go('app.current-trip').closetripInfo();
}
```

It works BUT it does not look right to me and I am getting an error.. I haven't been successful on doing it correctly. Perhaps is not that simple. I also think that I might need to be aware of best practices like promises?

**THE ERROR**

**TypeError: $state.go(...).closetripInfo is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.onSwipeRight**

Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated.Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use AngularJS promises to run functions asynchronously. Promises in AngularJS are provided by the built-in `$q` service.You can read upon it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
$scope.onSwipeRight = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve('res');

  $state.go('app.current-trip');

  // We return a promise
  return deferred.promise;
}


onSwipeRight().then(function(res) {
   // Success callback
   $scope.closetripInfo();
},null);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/midhunadarvin/n19s8o1L/) on using the `$q` service. Also this is a good blog [post](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) where promises are explained as a cartoon.

Comment: Midhun! This is great and exactly that I was thinking however I did not know the proper way to execute this! Thank you!